# Is it possible to register a custom gamepad in javascript with the Gamepad API?

Tags: javascript, aframe, webvr, gamepad, gamepad-api

**Quick background**

I am currently working on a VR application with A-frame to showcase VR hardware. We use custom controllers that connects through websocket/bluetooth and would like to make them compatible with the [tracked-controls](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/v0.7.0/src/components/tracked-controls.js). Those A-Frame components use the Gamepad API to update model positionning and orientation and are compatible with other components that simulate hands, etc.

**Why register the gamepad using javascript?**

The tracked-controls use the gamepad api to update themselves so being able to put our own gamepad in the navigator.getGamepads list and updating the data of the gamepad would be perfect. However, the current controllers are constantly changing and having a browser specific implementation like the vive is impossible.

Is it possible to register a custom gamepad in javascript with the Gamepad API?

Comment: A key question: Does your custom controller return pose information? tracked-controls is primarily for 3-dof and 6-dof controllers. It currently does not handle 0-dof controllers like the Gear VR headset touchpad and the virtual controller in Chrome's VR mode (though there currently discussion on whether that will be added).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to add entries to [`navigator.getGamepads()`](https://w3c.github.io/gamepad/#dom-navigator-getgamepads). Your custom controllers could potentially emulate a well-known controller using a project like [this](https://github.com/ViGEm/ViGEmBus), but your mileage with this approach may vary and be OS-specific.